# Php какой из циклов будет быстрее выполняться?как проверить? и почему?

Tags: html, циклы, php

```
<?php
$arr=range(0,1000);

//for one
$i=0;
for (; ; ){
    if($i>$count($arr)){
        break;
    }
    echo $i;
    $i++;
}
//for two
for ($i=0;$i<=count($arr); $i++){
    echo $i;
}
//for  three
for ($i=0,$size=count($arr); $i<=$size;++$i){
    echo $i;
}
?>
```

Comment: Думаю разница будет настолько минимальна что не повлияет на конечный результат. Если $i используется в контексте индекса массива $arr то используйте `foreach` будет намного понятнее, чем `($i=0,$size=count($arr); $i<=$size;++$i)` а вместо такой "сумасшедшей" конструкции `for (; ; ){ }` я бы использовал `while(true) {}`

Comment: не экономьте на спичках. Вы пишете не на ассемблере и не на Си, и ваша программа - это не драйвер для программируемого утюга, где важны каждый такт и каждый байт. PHP, обменивающийся запросами/ответами с клиентом и базой данных уж точно не нуждается в столь бессмысленных оптимизациях циклов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> как проверить?

быстро

```
$timings = array();
$tag = microtime(true);
// исследуемый код #1
$timings[] = microtime(true) - $tag;
$tag = microtime(true);
// исследуемый код #1
$timings[] = microtime(true) - $tag;
foreach ($timings as $key => $ns) {
    printf('Выполнение кода %d заняло %f секунд'.PHP_EOL, $key, $ns);
}
```

красиво, с возможностью написать кучу тестов и сравнивать производительность от релиза к релизу - https://github.com/polyfractal/athletic (athletic/athletic на packagist)

Answer (score 2):

можно проверять время, затраченное на выполнения набора функций и операторов, функцией **microtime()**

В данной ситуации разницы вообще нет.

Разве что, в первом - переменная глобальная, а в третьем - вызывается count единожды, что на 0.1% быстрее))